# Data lost when deploying code AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I’m having a problem when I deploy a new version of my ruby on rails application to AWS using elastic beanstalk.

I’ve tried using both a new DB instance as well as an existing one and both times I lose all the data in my RDS DB every time a new version of my code is deployed.

I’m not sure if it is a problem with my application or my connection with the DB.

Im currently connecting to the DB using the following bit of code (i took out my info) in the .elasticbeanstalk < config.yml file.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Again, the database works and information is stored, it’s only upon deploying that all data is lost. I’m wondering if there is a way to avoid this loss of data from occurring?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see how the way you are connecting to the database would have any bearing on this issue. Are you sure you aren't running something like `rake db:reset` as part of the deployment process?

Comment: Hi @MarkB, i am pretty sure i am not reseting the DB when i deploy. I also dont think that connecting the database should create any issues but i have no idea what could be causing this problem

Comment: Then you should be posting your deployment setup so people can review it